# ORM for high persistence but simple schema DB?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, orm, jooq

I am currently on the design phase of a Java project that requires a database to have a high persistence (writing and reading) activity. Although we are trying to reduce CRUD operations with caching it still will have a medium level concurrency and medium-high level of persistence. On the plus side the DB schema is quite simple, so we probably we will writing on a few fields of a set of simple tables.
Tables may contain up to +20K entries

Now, many of the designers are not so prone to use ORMs (I am quite familiar with Hibernate and Spring DAO). They adduce that Hibernate have too high performance overhead. Is this true? Is there any ORM that may be a better suit for this project? Mybatis, Spring DAO?. Has anyone experience on Ebean ORM, jooq, or other not so-known ORM? Is there any way I can ensure that ORM may not become a bottleneck?

Comment: 20K is not a lot of data. What do you mean high activity? How many concurrent clients, how frequently are they going to perform data operations and what operations are these? Not much reason to look into ORM performance if they work with 5-10 objects every 1 minute.

Comment: Do you need an ORM or could you start with Spring JDBCTemplate for helping reducing boilerplate? It probably depends on how complex your schema is. Do you need to support multiple RDBMS?

Comment: On the other hand, ORMs are completely inappropriate for reporting - no business functionality means no entities. Reporting is just data rows. An ORM that tries to load even 1000 rows can get you into trouble fast

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I mean I may have around 500 - 3k concurrent users each one making about one reading-writing operation every 4 seconds. -- I don't think I will do much reporting. That last thing you say about the ORM trying to load multiple lines is one of my major concerns.

Comment: @MickMnemonic There is no a plan to support multiple RDBMS but we may implement another RDBMS in the future. I think Spring JDBCTemplate could be a good starting point.

Comment: Hibernate, like any other ORM, can have high perf overhead if abusing it, or using complex mappings/dependencies. What I would do in your position is to investigate multiple ORMs as well as your own implementation, and stress and perf test them under conditions you expect, as well as high and low outliers, and compare results. Hibernate  may perform well for one team, but not well for another, and it may or may not be the result of Hibernate, it could just be implemented or fine-tuned improperly by the team using it.